# Why does AWS CLI need access/secret key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam

If I already assigned an IAM role to my ec2 instance, and I want to use AWS CLI from that instance, why does it require me to put in the access/secret key, isn't that kind of redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it. [As the readme says](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli):

> The quickest way to get started is to run the aws configure command:

That doesn't mean it's the only way.

For IAM roles, you don't need to do anything, it'll work correctly out of the box:

> The final option for credentials is highly recommended if you are using aws-cli on an EC2 instance. IAM Roles are a great way to have credentials installed automatically on your instance. If you are using IAM Roles, aws-cli will find them and use them automatically.

(also from the readme).

Answer (score 2):

You are not *required* to enter an access key/secret key.

The AWS documentation for [Configuring the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) tells us the following about the credentials *provider chain*:

> The AWS CLI looks for credentials and configuration settings in the
>   following order:
>
> - **Command Line Options** – `region`, `output` format and `profile` can be    specified as command options to override default settings.
> - **Environment Variables** – `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, etc.
> - **The AWS credentials file** – located at `~/.aws/credentials` on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\credentials` on
>     Windows. This file can contain multiple named profiles in addition to
>     a default profile.
> - **The CLI configuration file** – typically located at `~/.aws/config` on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config` on
>     Windows. This file can contain a default profile, named profiles, and
>     CLI specific configuration parameters for each.
> - **Instance profile credentials** – these credentials can be used on EC2 instances with an assigned instance role, and are delivered
>     through the Amazon EC2 metadata service.

If you configure credentials then these *will* be used, however configure nothing and you should be good to go with your existing Instance Profile and IAM Role.